# Spark nested JSON aggregation

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have the following schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Measurements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metric: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

In my analyses I'd like to keep the nested structure as-is but would like to add columns to the DataFrame that contain the number of elements in `Measurements`, the min/max/avg value for some columns, particularly `value` for certain values of `metric`, e.g. `'temperature'`.

In a SQLContext I can simply use `sqlContext.sql("SELECT Id, SIZE(Measurements) AS num_entries FROM df"` to get the size, but I was wondering whether there is an elegant way (in Scala) to do what I'm trying to do, i.e. without creating new DataFrames that have to be joined back in based on `Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(df("id"), size(df("Measurements"))).collect
```

Above should work. For more builtin functions follow https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal approach here. Simple metrics, like the number of elements in an `array`, can be easily extracted using built-in functions (`size`).

```
case class Measurement(temperature: Double, speed: Double)

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, Array(Measurement(0.5, 10.0), Measurement(6.2, 3.7))),
  (2L, Array(Measurement(22.0, 5.0)))
)).toDF("id", "measurements")

df.select($"*", size($"measurements")).show

// +---+--------------------+------------------+
// | id|        measurements|size(measurements)|
// +---+--------------------+------------------+
// |  1|[[0.5,10.0], [6.2...|                 2|
// |  2|        [[22.0,5.0]]|                 1|
// +---+--------------------+------------------+
```

More complex things require either `exploding`:

```
val expanded = df.withColumn("measurement",explode($"measurements"))
val withStats = expanded
 .groupBy($"id")
 .agg(
   avg($"measurement.temperature").alias("avg_temp"),
   avg($"measurement.speed").alias("avg_speed"),
   first($"measurements")) // This assumes a single row per ID!

withStats.show
// +---+--------+---------+---------------------+
// | id|avg_temp|avg_speed|first(measurements)()|
// +---+--------+---------+---------------------+
// |  1|    3.35|     6.85| [[0.5,10.0], [6.2...|
// |  2|    22.0|      5.0|         [[22.0,5.0]]|
// +---+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

or UDFs (something you want to avoid in PySpark):

```
def my_mean(c: String) = udf((xs: Seq[Row]) => 
   Try(xs.map(_.getAs[Double](c)).sum / xs.size).toOption
)

val withAvgTemp = df.withColumn(
  "avg_temperature", my_mean("temperature")($"measurements"))

withAvgTemp.show
// +---+--------------------+---------------+
// | id|        measurements|avg_temperature|
// +---+--------------------+---------------+
// |  1|[[0.5,10.0], [6.2...|           3.35|
// |  2|        [[22.0,5.0]]|           22.0|
// +---+--------------------+---------------+
```

You can also try Spark `DataSets` but these are still far from stable.

In general nested structures are useful mostly for importing (and optionally exporting), otherwise these are second class objects.

**Note** *(Spark < 1.5)*:

If you use older version of Spark you can use some of the above with `selectExpr` (it will require `HiveContext`):

```
df.selectExpr("id", "size(measurements) AS n")
df.selectExpr("id", "explode(measurements) AS measurement")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My problem seems to be limited to the version: I'm stuck with 1.4.1 and the size function is available since 1.5.0... Bummer!

Comment: There is always `selectExpr` :)